# Specifying URLs within PHP document for outside world

Tags: php, html, http, url, localhost

I'm building a website from scratch using PHP, and none of my URL links are working. They all refer the client to `localhost`; whereas they are on IP, not `localhost`.

```
if ($user) {
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url=http://localhost/profile.php\">";   
    exit();
}
```

This sends the client to a dead-end, i.e. their own localhost. What should I do?

Comment: use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` instead of localhost

Comment: your sample will redirect users to their own localhost

Comment: You should use relative url's. `url=profile.php` will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

give the ipaddress instead of giving localhost like

http://192.168.10.3/profile.php

Comment: So if I bring my server down for maintenance, it obviously won't be serving on 192.168.10.3, so how will the links work within localhost? Is there a way of dynamically linking localhost/IP at the same time?

Comment: I think this code will help you                                                                                                                            `<?php  


$localIP = getHostByName(getHostName());

 if ($user) {
       echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url=http://"$localIP"/profile.php\">";    
       exit();
    }

?>`